# Serializing form doesn't work and I can't find the mistake...:(

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, serialization

He there,

I have this jQuery code:

```
$('body').on('change','form#item-form', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    console.log( data );
});
```

and an form (inserted via query).

```
<form id="item-form" class="input-item-view">
    <label>ID</label><input id="1" value="' + jsData[i].id + '" /><br>
    <label>Autor</label><input id="2" value="' + jsData[i].Autor + '" /><br>
    <label>Jahr</label><input id="3" value="' + jsData[i].Jahr + '" /><br>
    <label>Titel</label><input id="4" value="' + jsData[i].Titel + '" /><br>
    <label>Kostenstelle</label><input id="5" value="' + jsData[i].Kostenstelle + '" /><br>
    <label>Standort</label><input id="6" value="' + jsData[i].Standort + '" />
</form>
```

I want to serialize the form data, that's all. But that doesn't work. Console doesn't show anything (empty values... so it reacts, but not more).

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `name` attribute in Form elements.

`name` attribute is must in Form elements.

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/nG7U7/)</kbd>

---

Add `name` attribute to your HTML.

```
<form id="item-form" class="input-item-view">
    <label>ID</label>
    <input id="1" value="' + jsData[i].id + '" name="ID">
    <br>
    <label>Autor</label>
    <input id="2" value="' + jsData[i].Autor + '" name="Autor">
    <br>
    <label>Jahr</label>
    <input id="3" value="' + jsData[i].Jahr + '" name="Jahr">
    <br>
    <label>Titel</label>
    <input id="4" value="' + jsData[i].Titel + '" name="Titel">
    <br>
    <label>Kostenstelle</label>
    <input id="5" value="' + jsData[i].Kostenstelle + '" name="Kostenstelle">
    <br>
    <label>Standort</label>
    <input id="6" value="' + jsData[i].Standort + '" name="Standort">
</form>
```

---

Read [form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form) and [name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.name)

Comment: OH ... That took me nearly two hours? THANK YOU! just forgot the name attributes...